# Getting Model & Movement from Blender to OGRE3D

Tags: blender, ogre

I just delved myself into game development. I have created a simple character in Blender, together with its walking animation. I am planning to import the model and the movement so that I could use it in OGRE3D. How can I achieve this? Will the import thing have to separate model and movement? Is there any good and comprehensive guide for this?

Comment: Just checking, but have you read this -> http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34309 . It kind of answers your direct question. Browse the forums for how to actually do skeletal animation with ogre (you have all the terms defined in that thread).

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking the for the same question, I achieved that by using a plugin called blender2ogre.